# How to get loop value outside the loop

Tags: javascript, loops

How to get the loop values outside the loop below example only prints the last value, For example if i wanted to print the loop results.

```
var result;

    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          result = i;
    }

    console.log(result);
```

Now how can i get the iterated values of the loop which are (1 to 10) in the console, because now i will only print the last value which is 10.

Comment: put `console.log(result)` inside the loop??

Comment: *which are (1 to 10) * - you have `0 - 10`

Comment: The whole point of loops is to iterate!

Comment: i wanted the result outside the loop not inside the loop

Comment: have an hidden element say an input. set the value of it inside the loop with your value desired. call the change event along for the input element. Add a event listener for the change of input and get that value which is obviously outside the loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the log statement inside the loop where you set the value.

```
var result;

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result = i;
    console.log(result);
}
```

If you only want one output statement, you can concatenate your results before logging:

```
var result = "";

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result += i + " ";
}

console.log(result);
```

This will output `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it is a perfectly valid answer-- you may not like the question, but please don't punish users for providing valid answers.  Upvoted.

Comment: what does this " " means in var result=" ";

Comment: It means I've defined result as a string, but when I defined it, I had no value for it, so it is an empty string. If I did not do that, it would be confused when the first value I tried to put into it was a number (i) and then tried to add a string (" ") the whitespace separator.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to log outside of the loop, wich is quite unnecessary in my opinion, may use an array? :

```
var result=[];

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      result.push(i);
}
console.log(...result);
```

http://jsbin.com/gogeluhavi/edit?console

If you want result make to log magically, you may uses setters and a Proxy, so called Observables.

Enter result=10 into this console, ive implemented a Observable for you: http://jsbin.com/xacujabuwo/edit?console ; You could also paste your for loop...

Answer (score 1):

The Above answears are correct but I would like to clear it up for you so you understand it too. 

In your original code you have declared the variable "result" outside the loop, then at each iteration a value is assigned to your variable. So that first time around "result" = 0 , second loop and the "result" = 1 and so on.
When the the for loop is finished it reads the next line which is your console.log() statment with the variable "result". The last time the variable "result" was modified was inside the for loop at the 10th iteration and thats where you let it equal to the iterator,therefore the value of iterator is 11. 

In order to  display something at every iteration, the console.log() must be placed inside the loop. Check below example

```
 var result;
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result = i;
    console.log(result); // prints at every iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt add jQuery tag I used only javascript.

Add a input hidden tag

```
<input id="idOfInput" style="visibility:hidden" type="text">
```

Set the desired value to the input

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
result = i;
document.getElementById('idOfInput').value = result;
document.getElementById('idOfInput').change(); //note change() is to trigger the event
}
```

Add change event listener and get the value set in loop

```
var input = document.getElementById('idOfInput');
input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    console.log('input changed to: ', input.value); //you get the value here
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```js
var result=[];

for (var i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
      result.push(i);
}
console.log("Result =>", result);
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42252437/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*